# Assign dynamic controller in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to Angularjs. I've tried a example in [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4ONO3fuWI3mxT4yGRZ0O?p=preview).

file index.html:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in ctl.dataList">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <textarea type="text" ng-mouseover="ctl.mouseOverFunc()" ng-mouseleave="ctl.mouseLeaveFunc()">{{data.value}}</textarea>
    <button ng-show="ctl.showCloseBtn">X</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

file app.js:

```
app.controller('FocusController', function() {

  this.showCloseBtn = false;

  this.dataList = [{
    value: "one"
  }, {
    value: "two"
  }];

  this.mouseOverFunc = function() {
    this.showCloseBtn = true;
  };

  this.mouseLeaveFunc = function() {
    this.showCloseBtn = false;
  };
});
```

I want to show close button when mouse overed every textarea like facebook chat in [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5S7XW.png). But my issues is when mouse over **one** of textarea then **all** X button was showed.

How do i assign dynamic controller to every textarea or how to do like facebook chat ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with CSS as well as AngularJS. I suggest you to do with CSS which is Simple. And Do your `ng-click` on the button.

1. This [Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/EydG1KOeLaIKN7zUaUDq?p=preview) is using with CSS and added ng-click there. Please check the styles and classes added.

**Styles**

```
<style>

    .field:hover .btn-close {
      display:block;
    }

    .btn-close {
      display:none;
    }

  </style>
```

**HTML**

```
    <div ng-repeat="data in ctl.dataList">
      <div class="col-md-7 field">
        <textarea></textarea>
        <button ng-click="doSomething()" class="btn-close">X</button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

2. This [Plunker Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/kBQSDR0lS1ruEscZfiek?p=preview) is with AngilarJS as explained in the other answer by [New Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/968155/new-dev).

   ```
   <div ng-repeat="data in ctl.dataList">
   <div ng-mouseover="data.showX = true" 
           ng-mouseleave="data.showX = false">
     <textarea></textarea>
   <button ng-click="doSomething()" ng-show="data.showX">X</button>
   </div>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, it would be best to create a directive for this functionality and encapsulate all the logic of clicking the "x" button, but for simplicity you could also leverage the child scope created by `ng-repeat`, and do the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="data in ctl.dataList">
  <div ng-mouseover="data.showX = true" 
       ng-mouseleave="data.showX = false">
     <textarea type="text"></textarea>
     <button ng-show="data.showX" ng-click="ctl.close(data)">X</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

`ng-repeat="item in items"` creates a child scope for each `item`, so you can set values on the child scope.

Here's your modified [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/NzTfyOrh9bg8rWECoiWv?p=preview)

**EDIT:**

As suggested in the comments, if you have nothing more complex than showing or hiding the button, definitely CSS approach is the simplest way to go. Use the above example then as an illustration for how scopes work.

Comment: As I know With CSS, we can't select a sibling and do show or hide on mouseever. So better use JQuery or AngularJS. Better would be AngularJS.

Comment: @New Dev My example is simple but this button can clicked in the future. Do you have any example for this case?

Comment: @ShijuKBabu, yeah, for something more complex, I agree. But in this case your approach with CSS is definitely best.

Comment: @Trigges, modified the answer to show how to call a close function.

Comment: This approach has a problem. Try to click on button in with this code. It will hide. You need to have a parent div for text area and button and apply directives there. But if yuou have a parent element, CSS is better